# pie doesn't display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pie-chart, syncfusion

I am trying to create a pie chart using SyncFusion bind in SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC, however the chart doesn't display, no error message found when I rebuild the code and it runs but no chart display. I wondered what could the cause of the chart doesn't load

I tried this code to connect the Syncfusion pie chart to SQL Server

```
string command2 = "SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE Item_ID < 10";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(command2, con);
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd1;
adapter.Fill(dataset);

for (var i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int x1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["this.Item_ID"]);
    int y1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Item_Score"]);

    data.Add(new ChartSqlData(x1, y1));
}
```

[image: Here is the output image]

CSHTML view:

```
 @(Html.EJS().AccumulationChart("container")

.Series(sr =>

 {

 sr.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.AccumulationType.Pie)

.XName("Item_ID")

.YName("Item_Score")

.Name("Item_ID")

.Explode(true)

.DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true).Name("Item_ID").Position(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.AccumulationLabelPosition.Outside).ConnectorStyle(cs => cs.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ConnectorType.Line).Length("5 %")).Font(ft => ft.Size("14px")))

.Animation(animate => animate.Enable(true))

.Radius("70%")

.StartAngle(0)

.EndAngle(360)

.InnerRadius("0%")

.GroupTo("9")

.GroupMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.GroupModes.Point)

.DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();

 })
```

Controller:

```
List<ChartSqlData> data = new List<ChartSqlData>();

string connectionString = null;

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

connectionString = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-V3QJAMBF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=My_Database;Integrated Security=True;";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

con.Open();

string command2 = "SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE Item_ID < 10";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(command2, con);

adapter.SelectCommand = cmd1;
adapter.Fill(dataset);

for (var i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int x1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["this.Item_ID"]);
    int y1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Item_Score"]);

    data.Add(new ChartSqlData(x1, y1));
}

ViewBag.dataSource = data;

return View();


[Serializable]
public class ChartSqlData
{
    public ChartSqlData(int xvalue, int yvalue1)
    {
        this.Item_ID = xvalue;
        this.Item_Score = yvalue1;
    }

    public int  Item_ID { get; set; }
    public int Item_Score { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Render method is not yet called at an end of control creation. I have added that and prepared sample based on your need. Please check the below snippet and sample.

```
@(Html.EJS().AccumulationChart("container").Render())
```

[image: Pie Chart]

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PieDB1343192459.zip